# How I can create a wizard multi step form with stimulus js and rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, stimulusjs

I am developing a Rails 5.2 application and I want to create a multi step form editor (like the Stackoverflow one for writing new questions) but I do not quite grasp where to start.

Looking at stackoverflow, the like minded questions and answers seems to be old and does not match what I am looking for. I want to avoid abusing jQuery if is not really needed, since as I realized, Stimulus JS could help me do that.

Comment: There are few other ways you can create smart wizard in rails
1. `smartwizard` jquery plugin
    Ref: http://techlaboratory.net/smartwizard/documentation
2. `Wicked Gem` which is specifically for steps
    Ref: https://github.com/schneems/wicked

Comment: Hi Fahad, thanks for your answer, but sadly, this is not the ultimate goal, to use `wicked gem` or `jQuery`, since I would like to avoid messing with the  controller but have rather a front end based approach.